# Disable Downloading in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I’m working on an app and in this app, I have a `ViewController` where I have a `UIWebView`, in which user can visit any website. I need to prevent user from downloading anything/any file using this `UIWebView`.

Is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a delegate method of `UIWebView` - `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and return `NO` for any request you wish to block.

If you wish to block all link clicks for example, you can check the `navigationType` to see if it's equal to `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`. If you wish to block certain files you can perform your validations on the URL of the request and check if it's a link to a file with a certain extension.

Comment: but how do I know that which particular URLRequest is for downloading? This delegate gets called for all URLRequests

Comment: Okay! say it's a link to a file with a certain extension (say, pdf), so according to my requirements, I need to display that pdf but user can't save it locally. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: okay, this was not clear to me...
As far as I know, when you load a pdf into a `UIWebView`, the user can't save it (in browsers you have an export button and other methods, but not in your own web-view).
Unless you are talking about using selection + copy and in this case there's probably a way to prevent it.

Comment: Oh my bad, I took a wrong example. actually I want to prevent any kind of file download from `UIWebView`, and I have not idea till now. can I achieve that?

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by "file download". In what way do you think a user can download a file presented in a `UIWebView`? Please clarify that in your question.